# Reshaping a complicated array error on anaconda in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So the issue I'm having is with this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise #distance calculations for later


background= None
accumulated_weight= 0.5
roi_top=30
roi_bottom= 300
roi_left= 600
roi_right= 300

#function to find average background value
def calc_accum_avg(frame, accumulated_weight):
    global background
    if background is None:
        background= frame.copy().astype('float')

    cv2.accumulateWeighted(frame, background, accumulated_weight)    


#Segmenting the contour
def segment(frame, threshold_min=25):
    diff= cv2.absdiff(background.astype('uint8'), frame)
    ret, thresholded= cv2.threshold(diff, threshold_min, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(thresholded.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if len(contours) ==0:
        return None

    else:
        #Assuming that the biggest contour in  ROI(Region of Interest) is Hand itself
        hand_segment= max(contours, key= cv2.contourArea)
        return(thresholded, hand_segment)


def count_fingers(thresholded, hand_segment):
    conv_hull= cv2.convexHull(hand_segment)
    top= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,1].argmin()][0])
    bottom= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,1].argmax()][0])
    left= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,0].argmin()][0])
    right= tuple(conv_hull[conv_hull[:,:,0].argmax()][0])      

    cX= (left[0]+ right[0])//2
    cY=(top[1]+ bottom[1])//2
    distance= pairwise.euclidean_distances([cX, cY], Y= [left, right, top, bottom])[0]
    max_distance= distance.max()
    radius= int(0.9*max_distance)
    circumference= (2*np.pi*radius)
    circular_roi= np.zeros_like(thresholded[:2], dtype= 'uint8')
    cv2.circle(circular_roi, (cX, cY), radius, 255, 10)
    circular_roi= cv2.bitwise_and(thresholded, thresholded, mask= circular_roi)
    contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(circular_roi.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    count=0

    for cnt in count:
        (x,y, w,h)= cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        out_of_wrist= (cY+ (cY*0.25))>(y+h)
        limit_points= ((circumference*0.25)> cnt.shape[0])

        if out_of_wrist and limit_points:
            count +=1
    return count       


cam= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
num_frames=0

while True:
        ret, frame= cam.read()
        frame_copy= frame.copy()
        roi= frame[roi_top: roi_bottom, roi_right:roi_left]
        gray= cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray= cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(7,7),0)
        if num_frames<60 :
            calc_accum_avg(gray, accumulated_weight)
            if num_frames<=59:
                cv2.putText(frame_copy, 'WAIT, GETTING BACKGROUND',(200,300), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255),2)
                cv2.imshow('Finger Count', frame_copy)

        else:
            hand= segment(gray)
            if hand is not None:
                thresholded, hand_segment= hand
                #Draw contours
                cv2.drawContours(frame_copy, [hand_segment+(roi_right, roi_top)],-1, (255,0,0), 5)
                fingers= count_fingers(thresholded, hand_segment)
                cv2.putText(frame_copy, str(fingers), (70,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1,(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.imshow('Thresholded', thresholded)
        cv2.rectangle(frame_copy, (roi_left, roi_top), (roi_right, roi_bottom), (0,0,255),5)
        num_frames+=1
        cv2.imshow('Finger count', frame_copy)
        k= cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if k==27:
            break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Which is providing the error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I26lY.png)

The error seems to be flagging in a domino effect, where it provides 1 issue, which provides another issue in another module that was being used, which used info from another function in the program, and etc. The image I've attached has the error I'm struggling with and do not know how to proceed.

I believe there should be no reason it doesn't work, but I can say that when my webcam's flap is closed (camera returns a black screen), it does work. It's when it receives live video that it falls apart (in other words, when the flap is lifted and the camera sees everything) and gives a notable "1D array when it expected a 2D array error" or so

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
distance= pairwise.euclidean_distances([cX, cY], Y=[left, right, top, bottom])[0]
```

It will work if you change it to:

```
distance= pairwise.euclidean_distances([(cX, cY)], Y=[left, right, top, bottom])[0]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).